# Trying to move to Ubuntu at work

Tags: email, calendar, task-management

I am trying to go Ubuntu all the way, including at work. I think everything is covered in terms of applications, as on a daily basis I use Skype, Word, Adobe Reader, and print via my WiFi network.

However, my company uses Kerio and Outlook.  Is there a nice and powerful app like Outlook in Linux I can use for email, tasks, and calendars?

Comment: Have you considered Thunderbird? (from Mozilla.org)

Comment: And, if you would not mind, please select the answer which best meets your needs, and click on the checkmark to its left as well as voting it up by clicking on the ^ , also at left. This shows others the answer which worked best for you, and helps them find better answers.

Answer (score 2):

[Kerio](http://www.kerio.com/products/kerio-connect/server) supports Linux and MacOS as well as Windows, and is web-based, so your company made the right choice to enable you to go Linux. It gives you a number of choices, and I can think of three Outlook replacements which provide the functionality you seek:

- [Evolution](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/02/09/replace-outlook-with-evolution-a-linux-groupware-suite/)
- [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) plus [Lightning](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/)
- [Kontact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontact) with its [Kmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontact#E-Mail) and [Korganizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontact#Organizer)

Also, you need not use Adobe Reader, as there are many apps which will read and display PDF files. Linux also has PDF editing apps available which will give you power beyond that of Adobe's Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is [Zimbra Desktop](https://www.zimbra.com/desktop7/help/en_US/Getting_Started/Zimbra_User_Help.htm) - it is strange enough thing, but it works and may be familiar enough for Outlook users.

edit: The Zimbra site was reworked, and to ease the downloading, here the link [to download page](https://www.zimbra.com/downloads/zimbra-desktop)

From its [FAQ](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_Desktop_7.2_FAQ#Is_Zimbra_Desktop_really_free.3F): **Is Zimbra Desktop really free?**
Yes. Zimbra Desktop is open source and free. We make both the software code and the application itself available to anyone at no charge.

Comment: Just interested: why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: I dont know. It is a valid answer